# Server 2008 DHCP some clients not getting IP

Tags: dhcp

Today (after turning on the server from an extended power outage) some clients are not able to get IP addresses. Some clients work just fine. Win 7 and XP doesnt seem to matter.

I have tried flushing dns, renew, disabling APIPA and even assigned a static IP. Even with the static IP it acts as if it isn't on a network. You can't ping anything. I have also tried resetting the TCPIP stack.

The clients that work can ping the DNS and DHCP servers fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: "even assigned a static IP" - Then it's not a DHCP problem. - "You can't ping anything" - This doesn't tell us anything about the problem.

Comment: Sounds more like a physical issue, really. Are the clients who can not resolve on the same switch?

Comment: Indeed. Check the cables and adapters. Also check the switch ports. Do all interfaces show link up? Is your switch managed or unmanaged? Can you see Ethernet traffic in [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description it sounds a lot more like a network switch, bad cable, bad NIC sort of problem.

Are you sure that the switch came up correctly and that the ports are on the correct vLAN?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It turned out it was one of the switches. Oddly the switch seemed to work fine on some of the ports...which is why I didn't further investigate. However after going back again and swapping cables around to the other switch I found it was indeed the switch. Odd never saw something like that happen.

Answer (score 0):

I've eperienced something similiar before myself. To fix this I first assigned each network adapter an IP address from the DHCP scope which they belonged to (and also pointed each adapter towards the correct DNS server).

After these settings were applied I then went back in and reset the network adapter to automatically receieve an IP address (and DNS address) via DHCP and that worked for me.

Sounds strange I know but it did work for me.